# Reading File Paths in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, powerpoint, filepath

I am creating a PowerPoint each week from some charts in Excel using VBA. However, the first slide needs to come from lasts week PowerPoint created.

The file path and name are both variables because they have the date in their title. I am able to account for this and have checked it with the actual file's name. It looks the same to me. However when I try to Open the file I get the ActiveX error/Run-time error 429. Any ideas would be much appreciated

```
Sub CreateNewPres()
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim objPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
ppApp.Visible = True
ppApp.Activate

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

todayDate = Date
myTextDate = Format(todayDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
myFilePath = "C:\Desktop\Main\" & myTextDate
myFileName = "\Meeting_" & myTextDate & ".pptx"
myFile = myFilePath & myFileName
objPres=_
   Presentations.Open(myFile)

objPres.Slides(1).Copy
ppPres.Slides.Paste (ppPasteEnchancedMetafile)
Set ppTextbox = ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=30, Height:=10)
    With myTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = todayDate
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
objPres = Presentations.Open(myFile)
```

to this:

```
Set objPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(myFile)
```

Comment: that's half the answer, what about `ppPres.Slides.Paste (ppPasteEnchancedMetafile)` ? you will get an error here as well if you don't refer to the slide number

Comment: Didn't work. Same error. I will post the rest of the code in case.

Comment: Verify that `myFile` contains a valid file name.

Comment: @BrianMStafford how does one do that?

Comment: Either step through the code and hover your cursor over `myFile`, or add a MsgBox to display the value of `myFile`.

Comment: @JackArmstrong try `Set objPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(myFile)` (since you are working from Excel)

Comment: @BrianMStafford please update you answer, since it's marked with "V", at least to give the correct answer :)